# To ArrayList once, or to ArrayList each time?

Tags: java, arraylist, hierarchy

I have a program which has a structure like this.

```
Document which contains (up to 20)
Chapters which contain (up to 100) 
Pages which contain (up to 20)
Elements
```

This structure is represented by JPanels in my program. Meaning this structure has to be visually represented, and I'd rather not make a whole complex of ArrayList (unless absolutely neccessary) since each JPanels have a ZOrder of component, and a getParent() method.

This structure is one-dimenisonal, meaning that the parent has an one-dimensional array (and when I say array, it's purely descriptive, I don't mean ArrayList or anything similar) of its children. Each individual element has an index which represents it's location in(on?) it's parent. Number of elements in a page, and pages in a chapter is inconsistent.

It's easy to get the child's index within it's parent, but what about it's grandparents?

Since the elements can be (and usually are) numbered, having a one numbered list per chapter, I'd have to know the index of element in the Chapter, so I can adjust the numbers when a new element is added to the list (it doesn't have to be added in the end).

This can be solved in two ways (that I know of, that is):

1. Have an ArrayList in each chapter that keeps all the elements. This would require me that, everytime I add a new element to any page, to add it to the chapter array too.
   To accomplish that I'd have to go trough all the previous pages, add up all the elements on them and add index of the new element on the present page to that number, the result being the index of the new element in the chapter, and therfore, in the array. And do that each time I add a new element.
2. Recreate the arrayList each time I need to get the order of elements in the chapter. Which again means going trought each page and adding each element one after another until I reach the end of chapter. And I'd need it each time a new element is added.

So the question is, which of this two methods is better (more efficient memory or processor time wise)? Which is more in the spirit of Java and programming altogether? Is there a third option that I am unaware of??

Chapter example:

```
Page one {
1. something
2. more something
3. nothing
.
.
.
16. still nothing
}

Page two {
17. maybe something
18. nope, still nothing
.
.
.
21. giberish
}
etc.
```

The question is: Which way of doing it is better? If you have a better idea, you can tell me, but I want to know which way of the above two is better non the less.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a tree. For some reason, programmers want to flatten everything out into tabular structures. You are talking about a tree, you need to either use one or make one.

Sadly, there is nothing in the Java Collections for implementing Trees. You can make them fairly easily.

If you have things that are different contained in the tree, but that need to be treated similarly (as nodes), then do a simple implementation of the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). A good example is a filesystem tree: each node is either a Folder or a File. If you both have them implement an interface called FilesystemItem, then you can put them into their tree structure.

Since you are doing a Document, I would recommend Composite.

Comment: But that'll require me to create two structures for the same thing, one for visual representation, and other used for calculating, which would double up both time and memory consumption of my program, both of which I'm trying to avoid. And can a tree tell exactly how many leafs it has on each node level?

Comment: I don't understand the double up argument. What you have is a tree. There will be an object for each node?

Comment: Okay, it wouldn't double up the argument, but what are you telling me to do is already done, I think.

Chapter is a JPanel that is parent to and contains Pages. Page is a JPanel that is poarent to and contains Elements. Elements are JPanels.

With that structure, I have a sort of a tree. But how could I identify the index of a element relative to a Chapter. Check the example: I want to get the index relative to chapter for "nope, still nothin". Relative to it's page, it has index 2, but relative to the chapter, its index is 18).

Comment: So now you are talking about something different. What you have now is a tree structure of nested ui components. While I would be the first to argue that MVC is not the be all end all, you are talking about 2 different sides of the equation here: those are interface components, you have to have a model for the document. That's what has to be made into a tree. I know what you're going to say, sounds like such a waste and so duplicative. That's how it's done, believe me. Go look at any framework that models Documents.

Comment: Hmmm... Well, the swing components already have somewhat a model incorporated in them. With getParent() and getComponentZOrder(component comp), having an aditional model seems complicating things, since I have to update both model and the interface. And the most important thing, the model doesn't give me any more functionality than the interface does (at least from one I need). Since my project is fairly small, I think I'll stick to the interface only method, although I was aiming for the MVC myself. I think it becomes useful in swing only after a certain level of size and complection.

Comment: @Karlovsky120 swing is in MOST cases very complicated and... ugly, if you talk code under it.